# Why does this code cause the compiler to report "Unused Variable" in Xcode"

Tags: xcode5

NSTimer *valor = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(update) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Comment: because you must not be using valor any where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `valor` somewhere else. Since it is a timer, you'd probably want to retain it somehow such as setting a property to it:

```
self.timer = valor;
```